# What specific bearing does `GeofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation ().getBearing()` return?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence, bearing

Is someone with some background knowledge able to tell me what specific bearing `GeofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation ().getBearing()` returns?

Because my thorough testing has shown me that:-

- The value it returns **IS NOT** the bearing that the user is travelling in when triggering the Geofence.
- The value it returns **IS NOT** the bearing of the Geofence location from the triggering location (or vice versa)

The [getTriggeringLocation() documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent.html#getTriggeringLocation()%20%22http://) conveniently doesn't mention anything about the `bearing()`. So can anyone enlighten me as to what the value returned actually equates to?

From testing it pretty rigorously it doesn't appear to be returning any correlation between my Geofence, triggering location and direction of travel?

Random number anyone??

[Test example LogCat extract]

D/MainActivity(13349): Location: (51.2758,-1.1168)  bearing:276.0 (calculated:277.6) Speed:55.07
D/MainActivity(13349): Location: (51.2759,-1.1175)  bearing:278.0 (calculated:276.7) Speed:55.18
D/MainActivity(13349): Location: (51.2760,-1.1183)  bearing:280.0 (calculated:279.9) Speed:55.28
D/MainActivity(13349): onReceive: passedGeofenceReceiver has received a broadcast 
D/MainActivity(13349): ENTERING GEOFENCE - NUMBER TRIGGERED = 1. TRIGGER LOCATION (51.2760,-1.1183) bearing:78

D/MainActivity(13349): TRIGGERED GEOFENCE ID: 1481037411000 Location:(51.2761,-1.1192)

Comment: When you were testing, where was the device positioned and what was the orientation of the device?  I have a strong suspicion that it may be using the geomagnetic sensor to determine bearing, if it wasn't able to get it from GPS.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Interesting theory. I'll do some testing with different phone positions/orientations and get back to you. However, for the purposes of my application I'm now just treating `getBearing()` as an irrelevance and am calculating my own bearing.

Answer (score 0):

`getBearing()` returns the bearing in degrees. `getTriggeringLocation()` belongs to class `Location` in which `getBearing()` belongs. You are looking for [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing())

"Bearing is the horizontal direction of travel of this device, and is not related to the device orientation. It is guaranteed to be in the range (0.0, 360.0] if the device has a bearing."

Looking further, I believe the reason it's throwing a seemingly random value for `GeofencingEvent.getTriggerLocation().getBearing()` is that this is pulling a location AT the point the event was triggered. While this returns a Location object, per the `Location` documentation,

> All locations generated by the LocationManager are guaranteed to have a valid latitude, longitude, and timestamp (both UTC time and elapsed real-time since boot), all other parameters are optional."

I wonder in your use of it, while it returns a valid `Location` object, seeing as it is the location AT the trigger, the "bearing" parameter is a phantom null somehow?

Edit: Wonder if for some odd reason the bearing is mirrored...
Take a look at the degree wheel below, while the bearings aren't exact, could be worth looking into. Maybe try adding `180` to the `GeofencingEvent.getTriggerLocation().getBearing()` value to compare returns? OR One is giving bearing via Counter-Clockwise and the other is Clockwise, per the wheel example?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wasn't intending to ask "what is a bearing?". Perhaps I had better reword the question. I know what a bearing is. What I am asking is what the particular bearing that is returned by GeofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation ().getBearing() actually relates to.

Comment: The particular bearing returned is the horizontal direction of travel.

Comment: @Illadept I'm afraid it isn't. Which, again, is why I was asking the question. I've tested it and it definitely ISN'T returning the horizontal direction of travel.

Comment: Make sure the `LocationProvider` you are using supports `getBearing()` with `YourLocationProvider.supportsBearing ()`, if so true.

Comment: It does support `getBearing()`, It returns the correct `Location` values and bearings when travelling (and a bearing of 0 when stationary). However the `getTriggeringLocation().getBearing()` does not. So I'll repeat myself. It isn't returning the horizontal direction of travel.

Comment: Is your Geofencing API specifically registered, `GeofencingApi.addGeofences()`?

Comment: All my Geofences are registered correctly, are triggering correctly, and are returning the correct `getTriggeringLocation()`. It's just the bearing that is 'wack'

Comment: My last guess is that the bearings are too close and messing with accuracy, you may want to try and spread them out a bit more? You may have more luck using `bearingTo()` with the grabbed GPS points.

Comment: For info I've added some LogCat to my question. You will see in this particular example the bearing I'm travelling on is 280 degrees. But the `getTriggeringLocation()` bearing is reported as 78. I would have expected it to be 280, (or maybe perhaps 63.6 which is the bearing of the Trigger from the Geofence). So where does 78 come from?  I'm not sure what you mean by "the bearings are too close".

Comment: I appreciate your comments. It's not a showstopper for me, I can just ignore the garbage bearing that `getTriggerLocation()` is feeding me and use my last location bearing. All I wanted to know is where `getTriggerLocation()` gets its bearing from because it seems completely random.

Comment: With reference to your edits of your answer, I agree that it is pulling the Location AT the point of the triggering. If you look at my LogCat example, the Location of the trigger is (51.2760,-1.1183). The last Location feed that I display before the trigger is also (51.2760,-1.1183). However the Location object has the correct bearing (280) but the "trigger" Location does not (it has 78!). [caveat - I do need to go back and check that the two Location objects ARE exactly the same as my logs are only displaying co-ordinates to 4dp so they may actually be slightly different]